# How to convert string to dictionary into python

Tags: python

How can I convert a string

```
s = "1:5.9,1p5:7,2:10,4:18,8:40"
```

to a dictionary like this?

```
s = { '1':'5.9','1p5':'7','2':'10','4':'18','8':40'}
```

Comment: I could not get any breakthrough which help me to fix this thing

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `dict()` and `str.split`:

```
>>> s = "1:5.9,1p5:7,2:10,4:18,8:40"
>>> dict(item.split(':') for item in s.split(','))
{'1': '5.9', '8': '40', '2': '10', '4': '18', '1p5': '7'}
```

Using a dict-comprehension:

```
>>> {k:v for k, v in (item.split(':') for item in s.split(','))}
{'1': '5.9', '8': '40', '2': '10', '4': '18', '1p5': '7'}
```